What answer choices should an "embedded" section in the 2025 survey contain?
In the 2024 survey there was a newly introduced "embedded" section.
I appreciate and was pleasantly surprised there's finally some coverage of the topic.
Building on that I'd like to see the section being improved, because in my opinion the answer choices were rather odd.
It seems like the creators took the quick ideas from feedback, intermingled with build tools that can be used for embedded. IMHO the section definitely needs some sharpening.

Assuming the embedded section is kept, which (new) categories belong there and which don't?
What are relevant entries for the categories that should be included?

Right now, I see four/five categories of answer choices:

Embedded hardware platforms [HW]
IDEs mainly used for embedded [IDE]
Tools that can be used in cross compiling [Cross]
Test frameworks for C++ [Test]
Tools, I have no clue why they were included [Why?]

starball thinks it makes more sense for them to go in a "build and test" section(s).
Here's how I would categorize the existing choices, comments added where I'm not sure:



Answer Choice
Percentage
Category
Comment




Raspberry Pi
38.6%
[HW]



Arduino
29.9%
[HW]



GNU GCC
29.1%
[Cross]



CMake
28.3%
[Cross]



LLVM's Clang
17.1%
[Cross]



Cargo
15.8%
[Cross]
Rust package manager


MSVC
8.9%
[Why?]
Visual studio?


Ninja
7.8%
[Why?]
It's a general purpose build system https://ninja-build.org/


PlatformIO
4.8%
[IDE]
Specifically for embedded https://platformio.org/


Meson
2.9%
[Cross]
Build system https://mesonbuild.com/


QMake
2.4%
[Cross]
Qt is also able to cross compile https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake


Catch2
1.8%
[Test]
https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2


cppunit
1.5%
[Test]
https://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/1.8.0/


Boost.Test
1.1%
[Test]



doctest
1.1%
[Test]
https://github.com/doctest/doctest


SCons
1.1%
[Cross]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCons


ZMK
0.8%
[Why?]
There's a keyboard firmware by that name


Micronaut
0.7%
[Why?]
Framework with Java and Microservices, I think    https://micronaut.io/


build2
0.5%
[Cross]
https://www.build2.org/


CUTE
0.4%
[Why?]
Maybe CuteKit? Very hard to google.




everything that you've named under "cross compilation", I'd just say "build".

platforms/targets: ESP32, Arm Cortex M, ARM Cortex A, maybe Cortex R (niche/hard realtime).

I think including platforms is a bit much. and IIRC, the past surveys don't include analogous things like target browsers / browser versions.

@starball The survey lists web frameworks though. Not sure what the embedded equivalent would be. I guess HW platform comes pretty close, maybe as close as it gets. But splitting Cortex A and Cortex M probably is too much, I agree.

Cargo fits under the cross compiling category for projects using rust as there primary language.

@user1937198 Thanks, so we know, how it ended up there. Then we only have the question whether cross compilation should be included at all.

Here is a list of tools I've seen in embedded that weren't mentioned.
One category I would consider pretty important is something related to electrical. There are also some languages I don't recall seeing on the survey that pertain to electrical (VHDL and Verilog).



Answer Choice
Category
Comment




IAR
[IDE], [Cross]
All in one suite for embedded development. Includes an IDE, cross compiler toolchain, C/C++ language extensions, and plugins for other IDEs. Supports ARM, RISC-V, AVR, and others. Most notably is FDA certified.


SPICE (Simulation Program with Integrated Circuit Emphasis)
[Electrical], [Test]
A tool for validating electrical circuits. Not quite an independent tool, but more of class of tools that can be found in other EDA software. 


GHDL
[Cross]
A simulator for VHDL that transpiles to x86-64 assembly.


Vivado Design Suite
[IDE]
An IDE for Xilinx FPGAs.


KiCad
[Electrical]
EDA software for designing PCBs.


Altium Designer
[Electrical]
EDA software for designing PCBs. 


VHDL
[Language]
A hardware description language.


Verilog
[Language]
A hardware description language.


Microsoft's HDL
[Language]
No public information on this that I can find yet, but Microsoft was hiring some people a while back to make a new HDL for use by their Azure Hardware teams. 



Here are some of the initialisms used.



Initialism
Full Form




ARM
Advanced RISC Machines or Acorn RISC Machine


RISC
Reduced Instruction Set Computing


AVR
Alf and Vegard's RISC


EDA
Electronic Design Automation


FPGA
Field Programmable Gate Array


ASIC
Application Specific Integrated Circuit


HDL
Hardware Description Language


VHDL
Very High Speed Integrated Circuit Hardware Description Language


GHDL
G Hardware Description Language


PCB
Printed Circuit Board




are verilog and friends really for "embedded"? aren't they for the stuff you embed stuff on?

Ehh, it's about as embedded as C and C++. It has a heavy basis there, but you could just as easily be making an entire microprocessor. FPGAs are fairly common in embedded (at least medical embedded), and the number of companies making full ASICs or microcontrollers are probably in the minority compared to those using FPGAs. Regardless, I still want to see more development stuff outside of just web dev, and it's hard to come up with a clean category that doesn't require over-specificity.

Very good input! I think that's an important question, we have to help answering: where to draw the line to electrical engineering? Personally, I'd say Altium is a tool for electrical engineers instead of embedded SW devs. But FPGA programming is definitely embedded software. I guess it's similar to cloud platforms: they are mentioned, but most people don't build them, it's just what their software runs on.

Maybe that's another category? Do people work with FPGA, ARM chips, some other architecutre? Also which vendors? Instead of AWS vs. Google vs. Hetzner vs. Azure, ask for TI vs. Qualcomm vs. NXP vs. Atmel etc.

I wouldn't say GHDL stands for "G Hardware Description Language", it's just a proper name.

@mkrieger1 I do agree that some of the initialisms are really not worth listing (AVR and ARM have historical origins that lack any value in clarifying), and while I would agree that GHDL doesn't need to be expanded, someone requested it, and GHDL self reports that as the expanded form: http://ghdl.free.fr/ghdl/What-is-GHDL.html

I would also include The Greenhils Compiler suite to it as well.
It's heavily used in automotive and I very feature-rich, especially for embedded devices.
It's not open source or freely available afaik, not sure if this is a criteria.
Further, RiotOS, RTA-OS and FreeRTOS might be a good addition as well, since operating systems are getting more common, also in embedded systems. FreeRTOS is already used by PlatformIO for ESP32 for example, afaik.
Also, fuzzing is a very good technique to find bugs and security threats in the code. Security is unfortunately not commonly looked after in embedded projects. A good fuzzer is AFL, but you need to compile the code for x86-64 or ARM in order to fuzz it effectively on a "normal" desk machine, so maybe not strictly embedded related.
At last, test code coverage is a thing also in embedded systems. Tools to get this are gcov/lcov, CTC and Cantata.
Hope I could help.

Thanks for the input! I'm happy to learn about greenhils, it was a blind spot for me. At the moment I feel like RTOS could be an overall category. I don't know how many people use RTOSes, if it would warrant own sub categories like RioOS, freeTROS, etc. We're mainly looking for things that are unique to embedded. The fuzzing and coverage tools you mentioned are general purpose, aren't they? Guess they could be proposed for one of the tools sections, if they aren't already present.

Glad I could help. Canata and CTC are the only tools, from my knowledge, that can measure coverage on target, which is very handy. Fuzzing is a more general thing, that is very useful when you take care of security. But yes, it's not exclusive for embedded devices.

Could you add links to the tools? Can't find both with a quick google search.

Sure. CTC https://verifysoft.com/en_ctcpp.html and Cantata https://www.qa-systems.com/tools/cantata/

I assume the section will only contain tools unique to embedded. If Testwell CTC++ is meant by CTC, it would rather fit in the coverage tools sections. You could add the entry once they ask for input for the next survey.

Add the links to the post please. So others don't have to search the comments :)

From my knowledge Cantata and CTC are at least therefore unique to embedded, that you can gather the coverage on the target itself. I'll add the link to the post.
